# Comparing DLL sets from the same app on two different machines

Tags: compare, dll, mdac

Is there a good way to compare the DLLs loaded between two machines running the same app. (And to replicate the process between N other machines, two at a time?)

Background: I am trying to track down a configuration/setup issue. It's the age-old, DLL-hell-type problem where an app will run on one machine but not on another.

I have eliminated our installer as an issue; it's stable but there are differences between the target systems. Different Windows flavors, MDAC versions etc.

I have tried: exporting EXE snapshots with Proc Explorer to a delimited file and using Excel to do the comparison. But this is very time-consuming and error prone. (I'm not ruling out Excel as a possibility, i just don't know enough tricks to use it to my ends.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com), using it, you can create a detour on all calls to LoadLibraryA and LoadLibraryW. This way you can monitor all files that gets loaded, and get the path to them. After that, you can compare the files in whatever way you'd like. If you need help using EasyHook, let me know, and I'll cook up an example.

Comment: With Process Explorer getting the libraries isn't a problem. It's the file-by-file comparison that is the challenge. I checked out the EasyHook link but am not sure what I would gain that I don't have with Process Explorer. Did i miss something? Thanks!